# How to make the connection between two conversations ( 2 skills )

Tags: variables, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, transfer, watson-assistant

I put a context variable "changeConversation == true" in first conversation for transfer to second convesation, and on second conversation i put in condition "fromRentier == true". Did i forget something ? Or what's the problem ?

Comment: This seems something specific to your implementation. Share more information or close the question.

Comment: The only current way to link to skills would be via either your orchestration layer, or via your client code. Other than from a dialog to a search skill, there is no built-in process to link two or more dialog skills. Hence we do not have enough information to understand your question.

Comment: @timd is correct, you cannot transfer from one Assistant dialog skill to another by setting a context variable. Nor can the Assistant runtime actually switch from one dialog skill to another at all, only from dialog -> search skill. Therefore you must have some other code in place which will pick up this context variable and switch the dialog skill being used to carry out the conversation, such as the client code in a server-side app that a web UI is talking to.